# If $A$ and $G$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $G$ is open, $|A \cup G| = |A| + |G|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I attached the book link [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-33143-6.pdf), you may check the proof on Page 47.

> Additivity of outer measure if one of the sets is open.
>
> Suppose $A$ and $G$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $G$ is open. Then $|A \cup G| = |A| + |G|$.

*Note that: $|A|$ and $l(I)$ denote the outer measure of $A$ and the length of interval $I$ respectively.

I wonder that, for the part of proof to the case $G = (a, b)$ and the deduced inequality:

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}l(I_{n}) &= \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}(l(J_{n}) + l(L_{n})) + \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}l(K_{n})\\
& \geq |A| + |G|
\end{align*}

How can the above inequality show that $|A \cup G| \geq |A| + |G|$?

I can only deduce from $(A \cup G) \subset \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}I_{n}$, that:

\begin{equation}
|A \cup G| \leq \left| \bigcup\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}I_{n}\right| \leq \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}l(I_{n})\\
\end{equation}

However, along with:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}l(I_{n}) \geq |A|+ |G|
\end{equation}

then both the inequalities are on the same side, so I cannot link them to prove what I desire. How did author reach his conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of outer measure: $$|A\cup G|=\inf\{\sum l(I_n):A\cup G\subset\cup I_n\}.$$

Then you already know for all $\{I_n\}$ covering $A\cup G$, $$\sum l(I_n)\geq|A|+|G|,$$

after taking infimum over these intervals you get the result.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer!